# How do I use semibold from the ebgaramond package?

Tags: fonts, ebgaramond

According to the readme of the [ebgaramond](https://ctan.org/pkg/ebgaramond) package it adds font styles:

[image]

What do I have to do to set a certain part of the text to semibold? What do I have to do with the sb?

Comment: Please tell us whether you compile your document with pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe that there are five font weights: Regular, Medium, SemiBold, Bold, and ExtraBold.

1. If you compile your document with pdfLaTeX, you're limited to using the options provided by the `ebgaramond` package.

   - Load `ebgaramond` without any font weight options to employ the `Regular` and `Bold` font weights.
   - Load `ebgaramond` with the font weight options `m` (or `medium`) and `eb` (or `extrabold`) to employ the `Medium` and `ExtraBold` font weights.
   - If the basic "bold" font weight is, well, **too bold** for your taste, you could load the `ebgaramond` package with the option `sb`. Note that trying to set both `sb` and `eb` as options generates an error message.
2. If you compile your document with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you have many more degrees of freedom if you do *not* load the `ebgaramond` package and, instead, load the [fontspec](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package and issue suitable `\setmainfont` and `\newfontfamily` directives. E.g.,

   ```
   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \setmainfont{EBGaramond}[%
        UprightFont = *-Regular,
        BoldFont    = *-Bold]
   \newfontfamily\EBGaramondHeavy{EBGaramond}[%
        UprightFont = *-Medium,   % 1 step heavier than 'Regular'
        BoldFont    = *-ExtraBold,% 1 step heavier than 'Bold'
        Ligatures   = {Common,TeX}]
   \newfontfamily\EBGaramondSB{EBGaramond-SemiBold}[%
        Ligatures   = {Common,TeX}]
   ```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EBGaramond}[%
     UprightFont=*-Regular,
     BoldFont=*-Bold]
\newfontfamily\EBGaramondHeavy{EBGaramond}[%
     UprightFont=*-Medium,
     BoldFont=*-ExtraBold,
     Ligatures={Common,TeX}]
\newfontfamily\EBGaramondSB{EBGaramond-SemiBold}[%
     Ligatures={Common,TeX}]
     
\newcommand{\qbf}{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\ }

\begin{document}

\qbf --- Regular

\textbf{\qbf --- Bold}

\medskip
{\EBGaramondSB \qbf --- SemiBold}

\medskip
{\EBGaramondHeavy
\qbf --- Medium

\textbf{\qbf --- ExtraBold}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You might also have meant, how to use both semibold and bold weights in the same document.  A template for LuaLaTeX/XeLaTex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures[EBGaramond]{
    Ligatures={Common,Rare,TeX},
    UprightFont=*-Regular,
    BoldFont=*-Bold,
    ItalicFont=*-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic,
    FontFace = {sb}{n}{*-SemiBold},
    FontFace = {sb}{it}{*-SemiBoldItalic},
    Extension=.otf}

\setmainfont{EBGaramond}

\providecommand\sbseries{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsb}{\sbseries}

\begin{document}
EB Garamond Regular \textsb{Semibold} \textit{\sbseries Italic} \textbf{Bold}
\end{document}
```

[image: EB Garamond sample]

Or PDFLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[type1]{ebgaramond}

\providecommand\sbseries{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsb}{\sbseries}

\begin{document}
EB Garamond Regular \textsb{Semibold} \textit{\sbseries Italic} \textbf{Bold}
\end{document}
```

The `sb` font series is reasonably standard, and defined in *The LaTeX Companion* by Frank Mittelbach.   The `\sbseries` and `\textsb` commands I define here are compatible with many other font packages.